# Que sucede con mi usuario root

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy intentando crear una base de datos pero no lo logro porque no existe ningún usuario root o usuario con permisos globales que puedo hacer intente asignar privilegios y también crear un usuario nuevo con todos los privilegios pero me arrojo
 `Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation` intente darle todos los privilegios y no me lo permite

Comment: Pues visto lo que te arroja, el usuario con el que estas ejecutando la consulta no tiene ese privilegio de **Estructura**

Comment: lo que pasa es que no existe ningún usuario root que podría hacer

Comment: Ejecuta esta consulta y comparte el resultado: **SELECT distinct user.User,user.host FROM mysql.user  LEFT JOIN mysql.db ON mysql.user.User = db.User
WHERE user.user like '%root%'**